# How is data stored in object storage?

Tags: filesystems, storage, object-storage

what really object storage is from the storage perspective?

1. I understand that any unstructured or static data is stored like a raw object in the object storage, But my doubt is how is it stored on the disk, Wheather the disk on which the objects are stored be formatted with Ext3, Ext4 or NTFS, Refs filesystem. If so then its just the binary data stored on one big flat file and metadata is stored in a seperate database for quicker access?
2. Or if the disk on which the data is stored is a raw disk without any formatting of the filesystem and controlled by some custom driver developed by each manufacturer and metadata of the object is stored in a seperate database for quick access of the object?